# Neumann series: Proving the existence of the inverse of an operator

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-verification

I am trying to prove the following using the Neumann series.

Let $X$ be a Banach space and let $T,\tilde{T}$ and $ \tilde{T}^{-1}$ be elements of $B(X,X)$. Show that if $\| T-\tilde{T}\|<\frac{1}{\| \tilde{T}^{-1} \|}$, then $T^{-1}$ exists and  $T^{-1}\in B(X,X)$. (Hint: Use $T=\tilde{T}\big(I-\tilde{T}^{-1}(\tilde{T} - T)\big)$.)

Here's my attempt. Let $A=I-T\tilde{T}^{-1}$. Then 
$$ \|A\| = \| I-T\tilde{T}^{-1}\| \leq \| (\tilde{T} - T)\tilde{T}^{-1}\| \leq \| \tilde{T} - T \| \| \tilde{T}^{-1}\| < 1. $$

Since $A\in B(X,X)$ and $ \|A\|<1$, $(I-A)^{-1} =  (T\tilde{T}^{-1})^{-1} $ exists and is in $B(X,X)$. Since $ \tilde{T}^{-1}\in B(X,X)$, $T^{-1}=\tilde{T}^{-1} (I-A)^{-1}=((I-A)\tilde{T})^{-1} \in B(X,X)$. Is my proof correct? I didn't use the hint in my proof. Is there another method to prove this using the hint?

Comment: The very last $A$ should be $(I-A)^{-1}$. Otherwise it looks fine.

Comment: Small thing: When you write $(I - A)^{-1} = \tilde{T}T^{-1}$, you have not yet completed the proof that $T^{-1}$ exists. At that point it is safer to write $(I - A)^{-1} = (T\tilde{T}^{-1})^{-1}$. Then $\tilde{T}^{-1}(I - A)^{-1} = \bigl((I - A)\tilde{T}\bigr)^{-1} = T^{-1}$

Comment: @DanielFischer Took me a second to understand what you mean. Thank you. :)

Comment: And the hint leads to essentially the same, the difference is that it uses $B = I - \tilde{T}^{-1}T$ instead of your $A = I - T\tilde{T}^{-1}$. (In other words, you use $T = (I - (\tilde{T} - T)\tilde{T}^{-1})\tilde{T}$.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your proof is correct. It is in some sense the mirror image of the proof the hint suggested. You use
$$A = I - T\tilde{T}^{-1} = (\tilde{T} - T)\tilde{T}^{-1}$$
while the hint goes for
$$B = \tilde{T}^{-1}(\tilde{T} - T) = I - \tilde{T}^{-1}T.$$
For the same reason that allowed you to conclude $\lVert A\rVert < 1$ one can conclude $\lVert B\rVert < 1$, whence $\tilde{T}(I - B)$ is invertible. And $\tilde{T}(I - B) = T$. Your proof showed that $T$ is invertible by writing $T$ as $(I - A)\tilde{T}$.